# I'm unable to remove the margin from the top of my page

Tags: css, containers, whitespace, margin

I'm unable to remove two margins. The one at the top of the page and one underneath my hero image. I've tried margin 0, padding 0, etc.. I've even tried to remove it from the body and html. How can I fix this?

```css
/* Setting up our grid */

html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  /*Set the width of the entire website here */
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  /*Margin-left and right are set to auto to center the container */
}
.seven:first-child,
.eight:first-child,
.nine:first-child,
.ten:first-child,
.eleven:first-child,
.five:first-child,
.four:first-child,
.three:first-child,
.two:first-child,
.one:first-child,
.six:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  /* This line of code makes the left-most column align to the left of the screen */
}
.eleven {
  width: 91.5%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.ten {
  width: 83%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.nine {
  width: 74.5%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.eight {
  width: 66%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.seven {
  width: 57.5%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.six {
  width: 50%;
  /* This div spans six columns (the entire row)*/
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0%;
}
.five {
  width: 40.5%;
  /* This div spans five columns */
  margin-left: 2%;
  float: left;
}
.four {
  width: 32%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.three {
  width: 23.5%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.two {
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.one {
  width: 6.5%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  /* Clear creates new styles for the next row */
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
header {
  height: 110px;
}
.hero-image {
  height: 767.38px;
  background-image: url(vintagemcdonalds.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.row2 .six {
  width: 50%;
  height: 495.56px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.row2 .right {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.row3 .lower {
  width: 50%;
  height: 495.56px;
  background-color: green;
}
.row3 .corner {
  width: 50%;
  height: 495.56px;
  background-color: black;
}
.follow {
  height: 908px;
  background-color: tan;
}
.bottom {
  height: 169px;
  background-color: grey;
}
footer {
  height: 169px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!--everything on the page-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hero-image">
      <header>
        <h1>Vintage McDonald's</h1>
      </header>
      <h2>Welcome to McDonald's!<br>Come and try our NEW Big Mac!!!</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--closing row 1-->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="row2">
      <div class="six">
      </div>
      <div class="six right">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--closing row 2-->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="row3">
      <div class="six lower">
      </div>
      <div class="six corner">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--closing row 3-->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="follow">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--closing row 4-->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="bottom">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--closing row 5-->

  <div class="row">
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!--closing row 6-->
</div>
```

Comment: remove the h2's  margin

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly >>> Try this:
Your CSS has class:

```
.hero-image {
    height: 767.38px;
    background-image: url(vintagemcdonalds.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Delete height:

```
.hero-image {
        backgrround-image: url(vintagemcdonalds.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And add new CSS style:

```
h2 {
margin-bottom:0;
}
```

Hope it helped...

UPDATE>>>
Try this

```
.hero-image {
            backgrround-image: url(vintagemcdonalds.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:contain;
    }
```

OR

```
.hero-image {
backgrround-image: url(vintagemcdonalds.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hey. I tried that and it removed the white space under my image. But now the image has been cut to about 20% of its size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/5.0.0/normalize.css
Copy and paste the code in a new css file and link it before any other file.

And try this to remove margin from top of the page:

```
.container {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

and this for hero image:

```
.hero-image header {
  margin-bottom: /* how much ever you want*/
}
```

or if that does'nt work then try this:

```
.row {
  margin-bottom: /* how much ever you want*/
}
```